# Can you make CSS rules that apply only on initial load (apart from default state)?

Tags: html, css, performance, hover, display

### Introduction

What I mean by applying *only* on the initial load is, for example,

( ❗ Heads up, I'll be talking basics for a minute ❗ )

```
div {display: none;}
```

would affect the `<div>` when it initially loads; it's selecting it in its default state.

And if I added

```
span:hover ~ div {dislay: block;}
```

, it would then be rendered when I hover over its `<span>` (this is for a navigation dropdown if you couldn't tell).

And when I take my mouse off of it, it would then take back (re-apply) the `display: none;` style; because that style was applied to its default state, which it is now returning to.

But I want it to ***fade*** out (using `opacity` first), which I can't do since you cannot add a `transition-delay` to `display` (e.g. `transition: opacity .3s, display 0s .3s;` won't work). [Animatable Properties Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

So, obviously, I use the `visibility` property, with all my CSS now looking like you see below.

### Main Code

```css
div {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .4s 0ms, visibility .4s 0ms;
} /* Leaving display: block; to be added by default */

span:hover ~ div {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .4s 0ms, visibility 0ms 0ms;
}

/* ===== The styles below are just added for snippet display. ===== */

div {
    width: fit-content;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 3px solid gray;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
}

span {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
}

span:hover {
    background: #aee;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span>Hover Over Me</span>
<br>
<div>Hey There.<br>How ya doin'?</div>
```

As you can see from the snippet, the result is as desired; it fades in and out.

### Problem

However, in my case, I am using this on **multiple large dropdowns** for a website, and when they are all not using `display: none;` anymore, the initial **load is impacted by 1.5 seconds** (which sounds crazy, but there are also images in some of them).  So **I need to have `display: none;` applied initially, but then I need it to not re-apply after returning from the hover state**.

For example, is there a CSS selector for only when it initially loads; something like:

```
/* When the page loads */
div:load {
    /* Styles */
}

/* ...as opposed to... */

/* Its default state */
div {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Is there anything like this or is it possible/necessary? Does it even make sense?

Or maybe some way to give it styles after hover (maybe give it a class with `onmousout`? But remember I'm doing this for multiple).

And please let me know if anything was unclear.

P.S. If necessary, I will include a link to the website, but I don't know if that'll get me flagged for advertising, so I didn't.

P.P.S. I'm aware there are ways to accomplish my goal (basically lazy loading) with JavaScript, and it's okay if you give me answers showing me the best ways to do it with JavaScript, but **I would really prefer a way to do it with CSS**, or to at least know for sure if there's not a way to do it with CSS.